# Why is unary not a legitimate radix?

Tags: number-systems

In binary the only digits are '0' and '1'. Let's define base-one (unary) as having '0' as its sole digit. There's an obvious problem, though - there can be no numeral representing zero, but there's also an obvious fix: '0' can represent (drum roll) zero, '00' represents one, '000' represents two, etc. '-00000000000' is negative ten in unary, for example. '$\frac{00}{000}$' in unary is a rational number, one half. It is clear to see that any rational can be represented in unary.

**Question: in what ways is this radix a misfit? It can represent any number base-N can represent for any natural N greater than or equal to two, or can it?**

Comment: A positional system is defined by multiplying each digit with its positional value and adding up. Multiplying with $0$ always gives $0$, and adding those $0$s up still gives $0$. What you describe is, of course, a way to write integers, but not a positional system.

Comment: This amounts to denoting numbers using tally marks, just with 0 instead of a line and an extra mark appended to all tallies so as to include 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that
when an integer
is represented in base $B$,
its standard form is
$n
=\sum_{k=0}^{m(n)} d(n)_kB^k
$
where
$0 \le d_k < B
$.

If $B=1$,
then all the "digits"
$d_k(n)$
have to be zero,
so,
as you have done,
the number of unary digits
for $n$ is $n$
(or $n+1$ to have a
non-void representation
of zero).
This seems odd,
which, of course,
does not rule it out.

From a practical point of view,
if $B > 1$,
the base $B$ representation of $n$
takes $O(\log n)$ storage
(more precisely,
$O((\log B)(\log n))$
bits).
Many algorithms working with integers
depend on this to have
a reasonable execution time.

My take:
Yes, you can do it,
and it might be OK
if you are programming
a Turing machine,
but it would almost never be used
in a real algorithm
or computation.

Comment: So, the main point is that unary doesn't fit the general standard definition of base-N? I can see that now. But unary _is_ capable of representing the reals, right?

Comment: How would you represent $\pi$ in unary?

Comment: π is irrational, meaning it has an infinite number of digits. However, it is impossible to write them all down. You can approximate π with rationals to any desired degree of accuracy, and write the result down (ignoring the physical limitations).

Comment: How would you represent 1/3 in unary?

Comment: $\frac{00}{0000}$